# Better way to generate a component array in a React reusable component

Tags: reactjs

I am building a reusable component for radio buttons. Naturally, it is unpredictable to know how many radios it will be needed in each case, so some how that has to be mapped in an array. Also, the component needs to respect the HTMl structure that it will render in and the RadioGroup and Radio buttons must be in the same component for scope purposes.

I have it working this way:

Component

```
const CMRadioGroup = (props, context) => {
    return (
        <RadioGroup
            name={props.name}
            style={{flexDirection: "row"}}
            className={props.className}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}>
            {props.radios.map(radio => 
                <FormControlLabel
                    key={radio.value}
                    value={radio.value}
                    style={{marginRight: 40, height:30}}
                    control={<Radio />}
                    label={context.t(radio.label)} />,
            )}
        </RadioGroup>
    );
};
```

Usage

```
<CMRadioGroup
   name="select"
   value={this.state.select}
   onChange={this.handleChangeSelect}
   //I don't like the part below
   radios={[
      {
         value:"radio1",
         label:"My First Radio",
      },
      {  
         value:"radio2",
         label:"My Second Radio",
       },
    ]}/>
}
```

It would prefer if instead of using it as a json array, that they were functional items that can be propped with functions and other props such as colors, onChange, etc. Something like this for example:

```
<CMRadioGroup
   name="select"
   value={this.state.select}
   onChange={this.handleChangeSelect}
   //This is better
   <Radio
      color="primary"
      value="radio1",
      label="My First Radio"/>
   <Radio
      color="primary"
      value="radio2",
      label="My Second Radio"/>
   ...
   <Radio
      color="secondary"
      value="radio-nth",
      label="My Nth Radio"/>
    ]}/>
}
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: you probably want to use `props.children` in your `const CMRadioGroup`

Comment: @Kunukn Tried that first, as I do wit all my components but the onChange and state would fire on load. Not unless I had the RadioGroup and Radios in the same component.

Answer (score 0):

What I can interpret is you want to pass radio buttons  as children to  component. you can easilt pass them as a clild. See example.

```
<CMRadioGroup
   name="select"
   value={this.state.select}
   onChange={this.handleChangeSelect}
   >
   <Radio
      color="primary"
      value="radio1",
      label="My First Radio"/>
   <Radio
      color="primary"
      value="radio2",
      label="My Second Radio"/>
   <Radio
      color="secondary"
      value="radio-nth",
      label="My Nth Radio"/>
</CMRadioGroup>
```

Do not pass them as props. The only drawback of this approach is that the component will rerender everytime of state change as children are treated as objects and react shallow compares the props (when using React.PureComponent).